# How can I fix this TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (3 given) for this specific example?

Tags: python

I´m trying to read a text file that is in columns formats, here is how it looks like:

```
AVP78031.1_NA   18 NLTG   0.7234     (9/9)   ++
AVP78031.1_NA   28 NYTN   0.7796     (9/9)   +++
AVP78031.1_NA   31 NSSQ   0.5689     (6/9)   +
AVP78031.1_NA   62 NVSW   0.7594     (9/9)   +++
...
```

My goal is to take the first, second, and fourth columns. So for that, I use a for loop to take the text/values in each column.
Here are the lines of

```
S_align = AlignIO.read("S_aa_MSA_pathogenic.fasta", "fasta")
with open("BatlikeSARS_N.csv") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    #print(lines)
result=[]
for x in lines:
### HERE IS THE TYPE ERROR
    result.append(x.split(" ")[0],[1],[3])
    #print(len(result))
    print(result)
```

This code gives me this error:

```
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
```

I partially understand the error, because I suppose that the split (0, 1, and 3) are correct; however, it's obvious that something is wrong.
Any idea to chance the script or add some lines is welcome!

Comment: The error message and your question title are not the same. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: Sorry for that, I going to fix it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to do:

```
for x in lines:
    splitted = x.split(" ")
    result.append([splitted[0], splitted[1], splitted[3]])
    ...
```

This will create a list initialized to have three items, the 1st, 2nd and 4th items in the split line `x`, and then append this new list to the `result`.

In the sample you provided, you are effectively calling the `append()` method with 3 arguments:

1. the first split item `x.split(" ")[0]`
2. a new list initialized to `[1]`
3. a new list initialized to `[3]`

Keep in mind that the comma is used to separate positional arguments for a function/method call.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `x.split(" ")[0],[1],[3]` is not correct, and secondly, you can't pass more than one argument to `.append()`. I assume that you are trying to create a nested list. Try something like

```
cols = x.split(" ")
result.append([cols[0], cols[1], cols[3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem here is that

```
result.append(x.split(" ")[0],[1],[3])
```

tries to append 3 values to result:

```
1º value: x.split(" ")[0]

2º value: [1]

3º value: [3]
```

But append only takes 1 value and it is the value that is going to put at the end of the list so, the right way to do it would be like this:

```
x = x.split("   ")   # Split the line
x.pop(2)             # Remove the 3rd element
x.pop(3)             # Remove the 3rd element again
result.append(x)     # Append the line
```

In this case I suppose that the separator is `"   "` (3 spaces) that is why in split i put `"   "`

Comment: This will append the 3rd column as well, which the OP wants to exclude.